# How to modify last column of a numpy array if maximum of each row is less than a specific threshold?

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy in Python and I am pretty new to it. I have a question which I have been trying to resolve by myself and despite that I havent been able to figure it out.

Lets say that I have a numpy array which holds probabilities from 0 to 1 and has 4 columns, like so:

```
print(probabilities) 
[[0.99859875 0.00126745 0.00011843 0.00001534 ]
 [0.9995454  0.00036321 0.00007128 0.00002014 ]
 [0.6         0.2       0.1        0.1        ]]

print(probabilities.shape) 
(3, 4)
```

What I wish to do is to check if the maximum of the row is less than a specific threshold (lets say 0.7 in this case) and if so then create a new column which will have a probability 1 and make the rest of the columns have probability 0 for that row. The outcome applied on the example above should be:

```
 print(new_probabilities) 
    [[0.99859875 0.00126745 0.00011843 0.00001534  0.0]
     [0.9995454  0.00036321 0.00007128 0.00002014  0.0]
     [0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0         1.0]]
    
    print(probabilities.shape) 
    (3, 5)
```

Does anyone have an idea how this could be done? So far I have just created a new numpy array called `new_probabilities` from `probabilities` like so:

```
new_probabilities = np.zeros((probabilities.shape[0],5))
new_probabilities[:,:-1] = probabilities
print(new_probabilities.shape)
(3,5)
```

But I am not sure how to continue from here. I would really appreciate any help you can provide!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the max of each row:

```
 maxima = np.max(probabilities, axis=1)
```

Then make a mask that tells you which ones are less than your threshold:

```
threshold = 0.7
mask = maxima < threshold
```

Now fill in only the rows of `new_probabilities` that don't match the mask:

```
new_probabilities = np.empty((probabilities.shape[0], probabilities.shape[1] + 1), probabilities.dtype)
new_probabilities[~mask, :-1] = probabilities[~mask]
```

Now you can fill in the last column as the mask:

```
new_probabilities[:, -1] = mask
```